# Android getImageData() from the inner image - SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, html5-canvas

in my application I am copying image on a canvas and then I am getting data from it. The image is in the root directory of the project.
This is a simplified code:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = picture.jpg
img.onload = function(){
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous');
var canvas= document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img,0,0,200,200);
var iData = canvas.getContext('2d');
try{
    var imgData = iData.getImageData(0,0,200,200);
}
catch(e){
    alert('error: ' + e + '\nimg.src: ' + img.src);
}
```

And here is an exception:

```
ERROR: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
img.src: file:///android_asset/www/picture.jpg
```

So, the image has been taken from the same domain; I did not find any additional permission for the Manifest in this case.
In addition I tried to get image data from the smaller square, like this:

```
imgData = iData.getImageData(10,10,190,190);
```

Why I am getting the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as that.
In MainActivity.java must've been a permission:

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

That's all.